# Custom search query for Elementor's WooCommerce Products widget, using the pre_get_posts action

Tags: php, session, woocommerce, elementor

I am trying to populate an Elementor product gallery with WooCommerce products, based on their post IDs.

Elementor's Products and Product Archives widgets don't support a Query ID (at least not in my version), so I am trying to use an alternate method to that in the [Elementor documentation for custom query filters](https://developers.elementor.com/docs/hooks/custom-query-filter/):

```
// Hook into 'init' to check for the '/shop' endpoint
add_action('init', function() {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/shop') {
        if (!session_id()) {
            session_start();
        }
        // Add action to modify the main query on the 'shop' page, firing on the pre_get_posts hook
        add_action('pre_get_posts', 'modify_shop_page_query', 1);
    }
});

// Modify the main query on the '/shop' URI to display specific products
function modify_shop_page_query($query) {

    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()) {
        
        if (isset($_SESSION['searched_product_ids']) && !empty($_SESSION['searched_product_ids'])) {
            $product_ids = $_SESSION['searched_product_ids'];

            // When logging is enabled, this line proves on each request that the product ID array is correctly making it this far:
            error_log(json_encode($product_ids));
            // Example output: "[155348,162360,162444,180967,179510,163383,165519,167079]"

            $query->set('post_type', 'product');
            $query->set('post__in', $product_ids);
            $query->set('orderby', 'post__in');

        }
    }
}
```

Elementor, perhaps in conjunction with the Astra theme, doesn't allow the setting of a Query ID for the Product and Product Archive widgets, as the Elementor docs would require in their method. It does, however, provide for a number of variations on queries, including Current Query, Sale, Latest Products, Related Products, Manual Selection and several others. Current Query seemed the most likely to capture the "main" query, however the product gallery is just showing the entire catalog. This suggests that the `$query` is being bypassed or ignored by the time it is updated.

Has anyone tried this method before? Is it possible?

Comment: Not sure what _'The product gallery, which is set to "Current Query"'_ is supposed to mean. Sounds like you might not be targeting the _correct_ query there to begin with, with `$query->is_main_query()` ...?

Comment: @CBroe Elementor, perhaps in conjunction with the Astra theme, doesn't allow the setting of a Query ID for the Product and Product Archive widgets, as the Elementor docs would require in their method. It does, however, provide for a number of variations on queries, including Current Query, Sale, Latest Products, Related Products, Manual Selection and several others. Current Query seemed the most likely to capture the "main" query, but you could be right. How could one test this, though?

Comment: I'd try and dump the global query (`$GLOBALS['wp_query']`) on the page in question, and inspect it to see what "type" it actually is.

Comment: @CBroe, I did a similar thing by logging out `$query->query_vars` before. Interestingly, the `post__in` array is in both: `[post__in] => Array ( [0] => 155348 [1] => 162360 [2] => 162444 [3] => 180967 [4] => 179510 [5] => 163383 [6] => 165519 [7] => 167079 )`

Comment: But to your question, the query itself is of the post_type `product`.

Comment: Can't tell what the context of this query is, if you are really targeting the correct one here. I would perhaps install a plugin such as Query Monitor, and check what database queries were executed for the current page.